# Is it possible to see which of my question earns me the "Socratic" gold badge?

Tags: support

Despite suffering from an acute Generalized Anxiety Disorder for a brief moment you know that feeling when you accidentally received a windfall of a significant amount of cash and you are stupefy momentarily, I am delighted to received 2 identical gold badges 4 hours apart but I have no idea which of my questions are the winning entries. I am wondering how to identify the 2 questions that added 2 gold badges for me because I need it badly to optimize my gold badge farming strategy ;D

Stay indoor & stay safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quite a unique scenario, somebody winning [two Socratic badges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/socratic?userid=8400) so soon after each other. Congratulations!

> Is it possible to see which of my question earns me the “Socratic” gold badge?

Actually, **all** of your questions contribute towards the Socratic badge. First of all, it counts the number of *days*, not questions; full details are in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. It boils down to the fact that you have between 200 and 299 "positive days" (days where you asked only "good" questions) and (as of today) you have a "positive question record", which (grossly simplified) means something like "more than half of your questions have been well received" (again, details are in the FAQ). Your good question yesterday may have caused that; it could even be an upvote or reopening of an old question. It's not possible to tell.

Comment: Thanks I see the system keep tracks of the overall health of my posts and just happen one of my question managed to hit 2 trackers at almost the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congratulations!

Generally, going to the help center and clicking on badges

[image]

then clicking on the badge you want more info,

[image]

gives the list of users having been rewarded with that badge and the post which was involved.

However, being the Socratic badge a multi question badge, you won't see the 100 questions.

[image]

You can go to your profile, question tab, list on date and see which 100 upvoted questions strike is involved.

Comment: Thank you I'll do some detective works then ;D